# Spatially adaptive smoothing using mgcv package in R

Tags: gam, mgcv

I am using the `gam` function in the mgcv package to fit spatially adaptive smoothing for heterogeneous data. This is my R code for fitting.

```
library(MASS)
data(mcycle)
fit <- gam(accel ~ s(times, k = 20, bs = 'ad'), data = mcycle, method = 'REML')
```

The output contains 5 smoothing parameters. I am trying to extract the values for each smoothing parameter `( S[[i]] for $i =1,..5$)` and I used `fit$S[[1]]` to get the first smoothing parameter values, but it does not work. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: I've answered this, but I suspect this will get closed quickly as the question is related to specific implementation in software rather than one of a statistical nature.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `$sp` component

```
> fit$sp
   s(times)1    s(times)2    s(times)3    s(times)4    s(times)5 
1.364206e+01 5.204389e-04 2.036490e-03 8.565542e+00 2.428618e+03
```

The `$S` component of the `$smooth` list contains the penalty matrices associated with the five smoothing parameters.

See `?gamObject` and `?smooth.construct` for further details on what is returned in the fit.

If you really want the penalty matrices, then look at the structure of the `smooth` component:

```
> str(fit$smooth, max = 1)
List of 1
 $ :List of 26
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "pspline.smooth" "mgcv.smooth"
  ..- attr(*, "qrc")=List of 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
  ..- attr(*, "nCons")= int 1
```

Even if there is a single smooth, the `$smooth` is a list. So we need `fit$smooth[[1]]` to access this smooth. Now if we look at the `$S` component of the smooth we see

```
> str(fit$smooth[[1]]$S, max = 1)
List of 5
 $ : num [1:19, 1:19] 0.4446 -0.2845 0.0913 0.0426 0.0943 ...
 $ : num [1:19, 1:19] 0.3417 -0.2441 0.0845 0.0341 0.0654 ...
 $ : num [1:19, 1:19] 0.0913 -0.0734 0.0271 0.0109 0.0141 ...
 $ : num [1:19, 1:19] 4.13e-05 -3.46e-05 4.10e-05 1.32e-04 -3.96e-05 ...
 $ : num [1:19, 1:19] 1.68e-06 2.43e-06 3.49e-06 4.62e-06 1.08e-05 ...
```

Which indicates that there are five penalty matrices associated with this smooth and that each matrix is a component of the `S` list. Hence, for the `i`th penalty matrix we need

```
fit$smooth[[1]]$S[[ i ]]
```

Hence for the second penalty matrix we need

```
fit$smooth[[1]]$S[[2]]
```

the first six rows and columns of which look like this

```
> fit$smooth[[1]]$S[[2]][1:6, 1:6]
            [,1]        [,2]         [,3]        [,4]        [,5]         [,6]
[1,]  0.34168394 -0.24407752  0.084500619  0.03412496  0.06538967  0.054028500
[2,] -0.24407752  0.36254851 -0.255915616  0.05368650 -0.03418746 -0.019895116
[3,]  0.08450062 -0.25591562  0.352961000 -0.21961696  0.04421239  0.001082056
[4,]  0.03412496  0.05368650 -0.219616955  0.35168761 -0.18138207  0.077301400
[5,]  0.06538967 -0.03418746  0.044212389 -0.18138207  0.25012833 -0.178018503
[6,]  0.05402850 -0.01989512  0.001082056  0.07730140 -0.17801850  0.264159096
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to display the values S[[1]] which you will see when you print fit$smooth

Comment: You asked literally asked for "...smoothing parameter values". If you want the penalty matrices then you should say so in your question.

Comment: Yes, I want to display the values of penalty matrices.

Comment: I've shown you how to do this now in the edit to my answer.